# Find a pattern (float +'\t' + float) in text file

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have some text files where I would like to find at which row a pattern with float+'\t'+float exist.

The text file looks something like this:

```
some information: bla bla
test time: 1.34
something else 23.00
data1 data2
0.01 0.22
0.2 0.34
.....
```

The text information before data1 can vary in number of rows and data1 and data2 can also vary.

I wold prefer a solution with pandas, but everything else is acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^.*\d*\.\d+\t\d*\.\d+.*$
```

This will help you to identify rows that contain floatTABfloat values

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/orLnP9/1/)

Sample Source ( [run it here](https://ideone.com/xgksjF) ):

```
import re
regex = r"^.*\d*\.\d+\t\d*\.\d+.*$"
matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)
for match in matches:
    print(match.group(0))
```

Comment: Thank you. Had just to do some "enumerate" in order to get the row number.

Comment: @AldinDelic as far as answers go, this isn't a great one. Always try to avoid iteration over rows. This is extremely slow, and is going to flop for large data.

Comment: @AldinDelic, glad to know that my answer helped you to the solution that you were looking for. If Apple is needed then orrange can not be consumed despite the fact that it may taste better for some.

Answer (score 1):

```
df

                        Col1
0  some information: bla bla
1            test time: 1.34
2       something else 23.00
3                data1 data2
4                  0.01 0.22
5                   0.2 0.34

df = df.Col1.str.extract('(\d+\.\d+\s\d+\.\d+)', expand=False).to_frame()
df
        Col1
0        NaN
1        NaN
2        NaN
3        NaN
4  0.01 0.22
5   0.2 0.34
```

To drop `nan` rows, use `df.dropna`:

```
        Col1
4  0.01 0.22
5   0.2 0.34
```

---

**Regex Breakdown**

```
(       # open capture group
\d+     # any number of digits
\.      # literal dot (escaped)
\d+     
\s      # any whitespace (sub with \t for a more strict search)
\d+\.\d+ 
)       # close capture group
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is there a way to keep the header (data1 and data2) ?

Comment: @AldinDelic You mean you want to assign the result as a column in the existing df?

Comment: @AldinDelic If I understood you right, you can use `df['Col2'] = df.Col1.str.extract('(\d+\.\d+\s\d+\.\d+)', expand=False)`

Comment: @AldinDelic Try: df = df.Col1.str.extract('(?<data1>\d+\.\d+)\s(?<data2>\d+\.\d+)', expand=False).to_frame()

Comment: @AldinDelic ^ .. if that's what you wanted

Comment: @Anup You can use `expand=True` and skip the `to_frame` call.

Comment: @AldinDelic Was there something wrong with the answer?

Answer (score 0):

You first need a means to find the floats.
Assuming they're always written with dots as separators, the following will do:

```
\d+(\.\d+)?

\d+            Match one or more digits
    \.\d+      Match a dot followed by one or more digits...
   (     )?    ... maybe
```

Then you will need to match the whitespace characters between the two floats:

```
\s+
```

All put together:

```
\d+(\.\d+)?\s+\d+(\.\d+)?
```

Tests with Python and `re`:

```
import re

regex = re.compile("\d+(\.\d+)?\s+\d+(\.\d+)?")

print(regex.match("0.2 0.34"))
print(regex.match("0.01 0.22"))
```

Output:

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 8), match='0.2 0.34'>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 9), match='0.01 0.22'>
```

Now if you want to capture the floats:

```
(\d+(\.\d+)?)\s+(\d+(\.\d+)?)
```

You'll find the two floats in the groups `1` and `3`:

```
import re

regex = re.compile("(\d+(\.\d+)?)\s+(\d+(\.\d+)?)")

result = regex.match("0.2 0.34")
print(result.group(1))
print(result.group(3))
```

Output:

```
0.2
0.34
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be asking about how to find lines containing a **tab**, not just lines with white space. In this case, wouldn't you need something like this?

```
>>> import re
>>> re.match(r'^(?:[0-9.]+)\\t(?:[0-9.]+)$', r'0.01\t0.22')
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 10), match='0.01\\t0.22'>
```

Notice incidentally the presence of the double back slash preceding the t.